# How to Parse this Data

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I am new to iphone can not understand how to parse this data so that, i will display the result in table view. Following  data is result of AFHTTPRequestOperation when i call api of megento.

```
{
        "callforprice_id" = 13;
        country = Austria;
        "created_time" = "2013-05-03 12:03:05";
        emailid = "indies.tester@gmail.com";
        message = hfhftrfygjh;
        name = "Richard Conover";
        "phone_no" = 8977896;
        "product_name" = Ottoman;
        "product_options" = "";
        "update_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    },
        {
        "callforprice_id" = 12;
        country = "Antigua and Barbuda";
        "created_time" = "2013-05-03 12:01:24";
        emailid = "indies.tester@gmail.com";
        message = sdfsdfsdfwe;
        name = "Richard Conover";
        "phone_no" = 5645;
        "product_name" = Ottoman;
        "product_options" = "";
        "update_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    },
        {
        "callforprice_id" = 11;
        country = Angola;
        "created_time" = "2013-05-03 11:58:51";
        emailid = "indies.tester@gmail.com";
        message = 6tyrtyryrty;
        name = "Kaitlyn Matheson";
        "phone_no" = 564564;
        "product_name" = Ottoman;
        "product_options" = "";
        "update_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    }
```

Comment: it's answer depends on how you want to display data. means in cell which item you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take this completely in an NSArray *jsonDataArray.
2. In TableView numberOfRowsInSection use return [jsonDataArray Count];
3. In tableview SelectRowAtIndexPath take a NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[jsonDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; In this dictionary, you'll get each object separately
4. Then you can access any element by [dictionary objectForKey:@"attribute_name"];

Comment: How to display only name and email id in tablview

Comment: NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"emailid"]];

Comment: Is it collect all the email id from my dictionary or only one. and how can i give to table view  for e.g myTableview.textLabel.text=

Comment: it will iterate through each object in array, the dictionary will have one object at a time so when the first cell will be loaded 
myTableview.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"emailid"]]; will print "indies.tester@gmail.com" from first object that is with "callforprice_id" = 13; and then when second cell will load it will print "indies.tester@gmail.com" from second object that is with "callforprice_id" = 12; and son on.

Comment: Thank you so much , I am new to iphone so does not know about it and nobody is to teach me from begin thank u so much

Comment: no prob dude. just mark my answer if u liked it .

Comment: @AhmedZ. how can i have only one entire record from the dictionary or array based on when  i select the tableview row

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29473/discussion-between-ahmed-z-and-bhupendrasinh)

Comment: Thank you Ahmed , i think there was problem in chat , i am replaying but does not show but i got the point that you suggested to me

Comment: no problem. good to hear that :)

Comment: @AhmedZ. I have done the thing that you suggested, now only one question  i want to display whole data in tableview like  for e.g        Name    :Bhupendra                                                         Emailid :something@gmail.com and so on is it possible in tableview ?? i have came across to custom cell .

Comment: no u dont need to use customcell but if u want u can use it.. 
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"emailid"],[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]];

Comment: do you have skype id??

Comment: this will show email and name on 2 lines. If u want to add more lines u can use detailTextLabel too.

Comment: skype id sent on chat.

Answer (score 1):

try like this if you want to show data in `UITableview` then use this one.,

```
NSString *str=[[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"country"];
```

(OR)

for getting data like dictionary

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in resultArray){
        NSString *str=[dict valueForKey:@"country"];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/

Check above link follow step by step process.

Hope it help to you